Clustering for a real problem - location matters!
I am working on a clustering problem and need some help to develop an appropriate mathematical model. Here are the details of my problem:
Locations: I have a set of 141 locations, each defined by coordinates (X, Y).
Groups: I want to cluster these locations into groups of size between 10 and 12.
Objective: My goal is to form groups that are as efficient as possible in terms of geographic proximity.
My question is:
Is there a mathematical model that allows me to evaluate all possible group combinations given the size constraints and optimize for the proximity of locations within each group?
I have looked into clustering algorithms like K-means and integer programming methods, but I am unsure how to adapt them to meet the specific group size constraints and proximity optimization.
Any guidance or references to methods, algorithms, or theories that can be applied to this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Let $L$ be the set of locations and $G$ the set of groups, with $|L|=141$ and $|G|=14$.  Let $d_{ij}$ be the distance between locations $i$ and $j$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ig}$ indicate whether location $i$ is assigned to group $g$.  Let binary decision variable $z_g$ indicate whether group $g$ is used.  The problem is to minimize
$$\sum_{1\le i < j \le |L|} d_{ij} \sum_{g\in G} x_{ig} x_{jg} \tag0\label0$$
subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{g \in G} x_{ig} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in L$} \tag1\label1\\
10z_g \le \sum_{i\in L} x_{ig} &\le 12z_g &&\text{for $g \in G$} \tag2\label2\\
\end{align}
The (quadratic) objective function \eqref{0} yields the total distance for pairs of locations assigned to the same group.
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns each location to exactly one group.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the group size if group $g$ is used.
You can either call an integer quadratic programming (IQP) solver or linearize the objective by introducing binary (or just nonnegative) decision variables $y_{ij}$ to represent $\sum_{g \in G} x_{ig} x_{jg}$ and minimizing
$$\sum_{1\le i < j \le |L|} d_{ij} y_{ij} \tag3\label3$$
subject to \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, and
$$x_{ig} + x_{jg} - 1 \le y_{ij} \quad \text{for $1\le i < j \le |L|$ and $g\in G$} \tag4\label4$$
